# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap when running IOUFlowTests.kt

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

I get the this error when trying to run the "Run Flow Tests Kotlin" in the example CorDapp (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example.git).

Preview of logs :

```
2018-05-13 12:19:36,091 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-05-13 12:19:36,098 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
[INFO ] 12:19:37,608 [main] (AbstractSecurityProviderRegistrar.java:113) eddsa.EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar.getOrCreateProvider - getOrCreateProvider(EdDSA) created instance of net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider {}

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap

    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader.<clinit>(CordappLoader.kt:75)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:221)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$1.invoke(InternalMockNetwork.kt:100)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$1.invoke(InternalMockNetwork.kt:93)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:374)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:363)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:358)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:211)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:194)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:100)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:217)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:211)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:214)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:214)
    at com.example.flow.IOUFlowTests.setup(IOUFlowTests.kt:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LRUMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 38 more
```

OS: Windows 10
Java version: java version "1.8.0_172"
Javac version: javac 1.8.0_172

Complete Logs:

https://pastebin.com/raw/1pN5B5gZ

Comment: To confirm, you're running an unmodified version of the `release-v3` branch of the example CorDapp?

Comment: @Joel Yes. Cloned from release-v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Clyde. This appears to be a bug. I've raised it here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3132.